# Mock testing try/except with print statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking, python-mock

I am currently writing a unit test for my Python2 script. I am having trouble writing a test case that catches both the sys.exit and the print statement to validate the exception. Any help would be appreciated.

```
except ParseError, e:
        if len(self.args.password) == 0:
            print('Some Message')

        print 'Login response error'
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Which print? How do you intend to catch an exit() call?

Comment: I want to catch either print statement. It doesn't really matter which one.

I am currently using the @raises(SystemExit) decorator included with the nose.tools package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mock sys calls and make assertions over them.

For example you can patch the sys.exit method in your test and then assert that it was called as follows:

```
@patch('sys.exit')
def test_whatever(exit_mock):
    // force the exception
    assert exit_mock.call_count == 1
```

For the print statement you can mock the `sys.stdout` call. A very concise example can be found in the [Python cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch14.html#_problem_226) book so I will not copy paste it here.